# Redux - I've changed my state how do I make things happen after this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writting my login system with redux and I feel I should have started with something more simple for my first redux :D

But:

**Reducer**

```
function application (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_REQUEST':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { loggedIn: true, shouldRedirect: true });
        case 'LOGGED_IN':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { loggedIn: true, shouldRedirect: true });
        case 'LOGIN_FAILED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { loggedIn: false, shouldRedirect: false, errorMessage: action.error.message })
    }
    return state
}
```

**Actions**

```
function receiveLogin(user) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: true
    }
}

function loginError(message) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        message
    }
}

export function submitLogin (creds) {
    if(creds.email.length && creds.pw.length){
        return receiveLogin();
    }else{
        return loginError();
    }   
}
```

**React**

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {

    logIn = ( e ) => {
        console.info('as');
        e.preventDefault ();
        store.dispatch(authAction.submitLogin(this.state));
    };

    render = function () {
        return (
            <app-content class={loggedOut.home}>
                <Logo />
                <h1>Welcome to <br/> Kindred</h1>
                <h2>Please sign in to your account</h2>
                <form role="form" onSubmit={this.logIn}>
                    <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.changed} component="input" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
                    <input type="password" name="pw" onChange={this.changed} component="input" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <button>Sign In</button>
                </form>
                <div className={loggedOut.extraDetails}>
                    <Link to="/signup">Don't have an account yet?</Link>
                    <Link to="/skip" className={loggedOut.extraDetailsRight}>Skip</Link>
                </div>
            </app-content>
        )
    }
};
```

So `LOGGED_IN` state changes. How on earth do I link my state with forwarding me to another page? I can't add any logic like this inside of my reducer, these must be pure. But I need to forward to the user to another page. I already have react-route which has HOC on it to watch out for people who have or don't have a logged in state. But this only on render :/ I can't add it to this logic as that would fire off every single page viewed.

Comment: I believe you have a "container" component that manages state and is listening to the store, right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of firing an action on success, you can just redirect if that's what you need in your app. Redirecting isn't a React component or redux action. If anything, it could be part of the asynchronous action creator.

Comment: This would explain things for me :D I guess only things inside of the view need to return state and update uI?

Comment: Indeed. Redux is for managing state. There's no need if you're just going to throw it out next by redirecting or reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to your store by subscribing to actions. Store.subscribe( handlerFn) should call the handler function whenever your store dispatches an action. Inside the handler you can check the state and react, pardon the pun, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a redux middleware for routing.So, once you are logged in, you can dispatch an action to be intercepted by the middleware and then it acts and routes to the next page. Since you are using react-router, the middleware can be something like this.

```
    /**  Middleware  */
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
let navigate =  ( path) => {
  browserHistory.push(path);
};

export default store =>  next => action => {
  next(action);

  switch ( action.type ){
  case ActionTypes.NAV_TO_POST_LOGIN :
    navigate('/postLogin');
    break;
  }
}
```